# How to make HEAD and origin/master point to same (latest) revision. (HEAD points to latest while origin/master points past revision)

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, remote-repository

I'm new to git-hub.

I need to update my commit with `-m "First"` from local repo to git-hub.

Currently `git log --oneline` shows below stack.

`394b23a (HEAD) First
895aa36 (origin/master, master) Second
dc7346a Basic Service
f627cd1 Data Binding.
.
.
.`

If I try to `git push origin master` I get the message:  "**Everything up-to-date**" and remote repo doesn't get updated. I think its because HEAD and origin are pointing to different revisions. I can't find a mean to merge both. I read about `git merge` but it mostly tells about merging two branches.

Please help to update the same. Thanks in advance.

**NOTE:** I have used `git reset --hard HEAD` in near past, which I think may be responsible for this mismatch.

Comment: Please show `git status` and `git branch -av`.

Comment: "git status": 
works: Angular/conFusion$ git status
HEAD detached from 895aa36
nothing to commit, working tree clean

"git branch -av":
* (HEAD detached from 895aa36) 394b23a First
  master                                          895aa36 Second
  remotes/origin/master                  895aa36 Second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git checkout 394b23a
git branch master -f
git checkout master
git push origin master
```

the `HEAD` is not stepping onto any branch,
then above commands do:

- checkout the target commit (you're already stepping there, but just in case)
- move `master` pointer to that commit (no problem, since it is a forward move)
- checkout `master` branch in order to be stepping onto it (for future commits)
- push (no conflicts, no problems, just forward then OK)

Answer (score 0):

HEAD-commit is not in the master branch.

You should check your branch `git branch`, current brunch will be emphasized by an asterisk. And after you should switch to master `git branch checkout master`. You can use `cherry-pick`, `merge` or `rebase` in order to add `394b23a`-commit.